# Mapping Identity Proof

Tags: functions, set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I'm struggling with proving the following:

Let $A$ be a set such that $|A| \ge 2$ and let $f: A \to A$ be a mapping on $A$ such that $f(g) = g(f)$ for all mappings $g: A \to A$. Prove that $f$ is the identity function of $A$

I know this proof isn't particularly difficult but I can't for the life of me come up with a decent proof for it.

Comment: Alternatively suppose you have $f\ne$ identity.  THat means there is an $x\in A$ where $f(x)=y\ne x$.  But we must have for *any* mapping of $g$ that $g(f(x))=f(g(x))$ so $g(y)=f(g(x))$ for *all* possible mappings $g$.  Well, just choose a mapping of the $g$ where that isn't so.  Let $g(x) =c$.  Now let $g(y)\ne f(c)$.  We have a contradiction as $g(f(x))=g(y)\ne f(x)$ but $f(g(x))=f(c)$.  So $g(f(x))\ne f(g(x))$

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is *not* the identity function.  Then there exist an $a_0\in A$ so that $f(a_0)\ne a_0$.  Let $f(a_0) = a_1 \ne a_0$.

Now for any mapping $g:A\to A$ we *must* have that $g(f(a_0))= f(g(a_0))$ so $g(a_1)$ *must* equal $f(g(a_0)$.

Well what if we decide to select $g$ so that $g(a_0)= a_0$.  As $g$ can be *any* mapping we can do this.  So we *must* have $g(a_1) = f(g(a_0)) = f(a_0) = a_1$.

Well, what's forcing us to do that? As $g$ can be *any* mapping we can have $g(a_0) = a_0$ and $g(a_1) = a_0$.

We have a contradiction......

.....

Okay... let's make this simpler.

Let $a\in A$ and let $f(a) = b$.  Select a $g$ so that $g(a)=a$ and $g(b) = a$. (As $g$ can be *any* mapping we can certainly do this.)

Therefore $f(g(a)) = g(f(a))$.  But $f(g(a))= f(a) = b$.  And $g(f(a))= g(b) = a$.  So $a = b$ and $f(a) = b = a$.

So $f$ is the identity.

.....

Okay.  Let's make this even simpler.

Let $a\in A$ but any element.  Let $g$ be the constant function $g(x)=a$ for all $x \in A$.  We must have $g(f(a)) = f(g(a))$ but $g(anything) =a$ so $g(f(a)) = a$ and $g(a)=a$ so we have $f(a) = f(g(a)) = g(f(a)) = a$.

So $f(a) =a$ for all $a \in A$.

So $f$ is the identity function.

....

To make it a little more sophisticated (but not as simple).

Consider the class of mappings so that for any $w\in A$, $g_w$ is the constant mapping $g_w(\color{green}x)=w$ for all $\color{green}x\in A$.

Then for any $a\in A$ we must have $g_a(\color{green}{f(a)}) = a$.  But we must have, as a property of $f$ that $g_a(f(a)) = f(g_a(\color{green}a))=f(a)$.  So $a= f(a)$ for all $a\in A$.